# Time Machine back up to Time Capsule fails

Tags: network, macos, backup, time-machine, time-capsule

Recently Time Machine has stopped backing up to my Time Capsule on both my MacBook Air and MacBook Pro. It spends a few hours "Preparing backup" and then just gives up.

I've had a look in Console and when it says it is "Preparing backup" `com.apple.backupd` is running an `initial consistency scan for '/'` and then when it stops I get the following messages in the Console:

```
Error writing event cache at /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/... : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=20 "Not a directory"
Error writing to backup log. NSFileHandleOperationException:***
```

The latest backup on my MBA is 23 July and on my MBP is 24 July so I think that coincides with me updating OS X but I can't be sure. These are the things I have tried so far (I've turned Time Machine off on my MBP so I can focus on getting the Air working first)

- Turning time machine off and back on again
- Reselecting the back up disk
- Hard resetting the time capsule
- Factory resetting the time capsule
- Booting into Safe Mode on my MBA and then restarting into normal mode
- "First aid" (Disk Utility) on my MBA
- Renaming the Time Capsule to a short name

The only thing I haven't done is erase the contents of the Time Capsule for two reasons. 1) I don't have a hard drive with enough capacity remaining to archive the data to. 2) When I enter Time Machine all of the backups are there and available for me to restore so I don't want to loose all that.

Please let me know if you have any ideas. The TC has over 300 GB of space remaining.

**UPDATE** Here is the contents of the `.sparsebundle` (located within the 'Data' folder) that is the backup (the `bands` folder is empty): [image: contents of sparsebundle created by Time Machine]

Comment: If you turn off Time Machine, mount the Time Capsule in Finder, browse to the Backups.backupdb folder, open the disc image that corresponds to your computer, do you have a folder called inprogress something? If you remove the inprogress folder it usually helps with TM not being able to complete a backup. Delete the folder and enable TM and try a "Backup now". Otherwise perhaps a screenshot of the folder structure on the mounted discimage would help.

Comment: @Niklas I have just uploaded a screenshot of the contents of the `.sparsebundle` as I don't have a 'Backups.backupdb' folder which I believe is because I'm backing up over the network? Let me know if you need any more information... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I wouldn't post an answer like this  (rather, just delete the question) as my solution to this issue is so untechnical; however, I feel that it might just save somebody a head of hair.

It turns out that the Ethernet capable connecting the Time Capsule to the network switch was damaged. I never checked it initially because the Time Capsule was appearing on the network and my MacBook Air would back up to it fine, but all I can assume is that my MacBook Pro but more stress on the cable. Long story short, I've put a brand new Ethernet cable in and it worked first time, flawlessly.

Now, before I did so I had followed [this tutorial to keep using the same machine after a change to the computer](https://nairteashop.org/keeping-backup-history-when-switching-to-a-new-mac/), so I don't know if that did have any effect or not.

I suppose the moral of the story here is that networking is a pain and you shouldn't overlook anything, even if it seems to be working perfectly!